# Understanding Promise within Promise Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have read: [Promise - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and I reviewed the section on promises in this book here: [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_http.html#promises) along with other google searches, but I can't seem to find out if this is a problem because my understanding of Promises or a mixture of libraries. What I would like to accomplish is make a request, retrieve the response, and then make another request using that response. I would think I could use the normal pattern of:

```
promiseObj.get('url')
.then(function(response){
    //do something with response
    var name = response.name;
    return name;
})
.then(function(name){
    //do something with name
}
```

But something isn't working correctly. I'm attempting to use two different promise objects to make requests. I have to make a request using the podio API, retrieve info and then use the AngularJS $http promise. Here is my code:

```
podio.request('get','/item/' + eventId).then(function(responseEvent) {
   ...   
   var imgId = responseEvent.img_id;
   ...
   return imgId;

}).then(function(imgId){
    console.log(imgId);

   var config = { responseType: 'arraybuffer'};
   $http.get('https://api.podio.com/file/' + imgId + '/raw',config)
   .then(function(response) {
        console.log('hi 2');
        var arr = new Uint8Array(response.data);
        var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);
        var b64 = btoa(raw);
        var dataURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+b64;
        $scope.event.img.src = dataURL;
        },function(error){
           console.log(error);
        });
});
```

In my second **then** i can see the imgId in the console, but Nothing happens after that. What Could I possibly be missing.

Comment: `imgId ` isn't a promise though is it?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud any value returned from a function passed to `.then` gets wrapped in a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create two promises, try something like:

```
p1.get(function (response) {
  // Work with response here
  return response;
}).then(function (response) {
  return p2.get(response.urlMaybe);
}).then(function (response) {
  // Work on second response
});
```

Massively pseudo but maybe of some help.

Comment: Thank you for this concise picture of how to return the next promise and then call then on it. It was exactly the structure that I needed. Is there a place in the google chrome tools or firefox that you can track the promises?

Comment: I'd use the debugger or some console.logs. I don't think I've ever seen mention of Promises in dev tools as such. Shout if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

One cause may be that you don't have an error handler for the outer promise, so if an exception was thrown after your `console.log`, the error could go undetected. I'd suggest you flatten your Promise chain so that *all* errors get handled:

```
podio.request('get','/item/' + eventId)
  .then(function(responseEvent) {
    ...   
    var imgId = responseEvent.img_id;
    ...
    return imgId;
  })
  .then(function(imgId){
    console.log(imgId);
    var config = { responseType: 'arraybuffer'};
    return $http.get('https://api.podio.com/file/' + imgId + '/raw',config);
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('hi 2');
    var arr = new Uint8Array(response.data);
    var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);
    var b64 = btoa(raw);
    var dataURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+b64;
    $scope.event.img.src = dataURL;
  },function(error){
     console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment on having the reject function. I caught an error in my variable name that was preventing me from executing the request. Thanks Alot!

Comment: Of course this still doesn't catch exceptions in the last success handler.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adrian Lynch's correct answer, suppose we have a series of requests. Each request depends on the results of *all* the previous requests.

```
promiseFn().then(function(resp) {
    return Promise.all([resp, otherPromiseFn(resp)]);
}).then(function(vals) {
    var first  = vals[0];
    var second = vals[1];
    return Promise.all([first, second, thirdPromiseFn(first, second)]);
});
```

..and so on, aggregating the values. The important thing is that every time you have a promise returning function call you just return the promise, and then you call then. Just remember that everything you return from a function you pass to then automatically gets wrapped as a promise of the value you're returning.

Comment: This was much needed advice. Once I got it working per you all's advice, my next question was how do I pass the results of previous requests. Thank you so much!